# c# Loops with stars and spaces

Tags: c#, loops

I am currently breaking my head over this simple assignment for loops that I have to do.

Basically what I want to achieve is:

1) User gives imput how long the star pyramid should be

2) Make a pyramid with a for loop.

It needs to look something like this:
(If it needs to be 5 stories high; first row is 5 spaces 1 star; second row 4 spaces 2 stars and so on.

```
    *
   **
  *** 
 ****
```

(Hard to format but you get my intention.)

I currently have this

```
    public void Pyramid()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give the hight of the pyramid");
        _aantal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= _aantal; i++) // loop for hight
        {
            for (int d = _aantal; d > 0; d--) // loop for spaces
            {
                Console.Write(_spatie);
            }

            for (int e = 0; e < i; e++) // loop for stars
            {
                Console.Write(_ster);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

The output is always the inserted number amount of spaces and it is not decremented correctly.
Although if I debug it it counts down correctly.

Thank you for responding.

Comment: You have to think of your "pyramid" as a matrix of characters, e.g. a 5X5 matrix. Then you'll need to decide for each item in each row of the matrix whether you want to insert a blank space, or a star. I'm not saying anything more.

Comment: problem is that you never decrement your total so you will always have (height-1) spaces indeed. You should at some point introduce `i` in calculation, for example : `for (int d = _aantal-i; d >= 0; d--)`

Comment: Do you want a symmetrical pyramid? Because you are actually trying to draw a triangle there.

Comment: Do you want a pyramid or traingle, with spaces before then stars..??

Comment: You have to have odd number of stars always if you want the pyramid..!! You cannot symmetrically create a pyramid with sometimes odd and sometimes even number of stars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give the hight of the pyramid");
        string _spatie = " ";
        string _ster = "*";
        int _aantal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= _aantal; i++) // loop for height
        {

            for (int d = i; d < _aantal; d++) // loop for spaces
            {
                Console.Write(_spatie);
            }

            for (int e = 1; e <= i; e++) // loop for stars
            {
                Console.Write(_ster);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Check this out..!! You were missing out the iterator 'i' of the height loop inside the spaces loop.

You will get the triangle :-

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

---

You will need odd number of stars always for a symmetrical pyramid.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the constructor of the string class to create the repetition for you, and then print both values at once, then you don't need the extra for loops

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int rowHeight = 5;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowHeight; row++)
    {
        string spaces = new string(' ', rowHeight - row);
        string stars = new string('*', row);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", spaces, stars);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**UPDATE**

for the semantics, i will then also show it with 2 for loops

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int rowHeight = 5;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rowHeight; row++)
    {
        int totalSpaces = rowHeight - row;
        for (int j = 0; j < totalSpaces; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The answer gives the correct result, but OP states it is a loop exercise!! If the solution uses no loop, it's no use to him.

Comment: Point 2 simply states "with a for loop", and this answer uses one. ;)

Comment: @boisvert for the sake of semantics, i used one for, but i also updated the answer with all loops ;)

Answer (score 1):

well, your problem is

```
for (int d = _aantal; d > 0; d--) // loop for spaces
```

you really want

```
for (int d = _aantal - i ; d > 0; d--) // loop for spaces
```

but it really just mirrors what you currently have, and still doesn't create the pyramid look you seem to want.

I think the closest you'll get in a console app is by subtracting a space every other row:

```
for (int d = _aantal-i; d > 0; d-=2) // loop for spaces
```

which will give output:

> Give the hight of the pyramid:
>   10

```
     *
    **
    ***
   ****
   *****
  ******
  *******
 ********
 *********
**********
```

Comment: Yes! is the minimal change on existing code that provides a working answer

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted to do this as a console app but if you adapt this code it should work fine

Replace **textbox1/2** with Consle.Readline/Write

```
    int pyramidstories = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    int I = 1;

    while (I <= pyramidstories)
    {
        for (int spacecount = 0; spacecount < (pyramidstories - I); spacecount++)
        {
            TextBox1.Text += " ";
        }

        for (int starcount = 1; starcount < I + 1; starcount++)
        {
            TextBox1.Text += "*";
        }

        TextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

        I++;
    }
```

As your question states you need: 
4 spaces 1 star 
3 spaces 2 stars
2 spaces 3 stars
etc..

so your pyramid should look something like

```
       *
      **
     ***
    ****
   *****
```

The code sample above displays a pyramid as illustrated above

Answer (score 0):

To get a pyramid (with proper spacing) like this:

[image: Pyramid example]

You can use:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The length of the pyramid
        int lengte = 18;

        // Loop through the length as given by the user
        for (int i = 0; i <= lengte; i++)
        {
            // If its an even number (we don't want 1-2-3.. but 1-3-5.. stars)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Calculate the length of the spaces we need to set
                int spatieLengte = (lengte / 2) - (i / 2);
                // Display spaces
                for (int spaties = 0; spaties <= spatieLengte; spaties++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                // Display stars
                for (int sterren = 0; sterren <= i; sterren++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                // Newline
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Obviously the if block and `spaceLengte` variable aren't really needed. But I thought it would make it somewhat easier for OP to read.

Good luck / Succes ermee ;)

Comment: There are all odd number of stars which is actually needed for the symmetrical pyramid, but he wants at a stage 2 stars and 4 spaces, that is even number of stars..

Comment: Aha, that block was formatted by my browser as a pyramid and not a symmetrical one. I just got editted with proper formatting a few seconds ago. Sorry for slacking.